# C# Using Youtube API - How do I check the last time a particular user uploaded a video to Youtube?

Tags: c#, video, file-upload, upload, youtube

I know how to upload a video to Youtube using Youtube API within C#

But I'd like to use the Youtube API to return a date when a particular user last uploaded a video.

My code for uploading a video using C# is below, but I really don't know how to do the above???

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.YouTube;
using Google.GData.Extensions.MediaRss;
using Google.GData.YouTube;
using Google.GData.Extensions.Location;

namespace UploadLimit
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string key = "somegarbage";
        string appName = "SlowUpload";
        string username = "blarg";
        string password = "blarg";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                txtFile.Text = dialog.FileName;
        }

        private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(appName, key, username, password);
            YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

            Video newVideo = new Video();

            newVideo.Title = "My Test Movie";
            newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
            newVideo.Keywords = "cars, funny";
            newVideo.Description = "My description";
            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
            newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag",
              YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));

            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = new GeoRssWhere(37, -122);
            // alternatively, you could just specify a descriptive string
            // newVideo.YouTubeEntry.setYouTubeExtension("location", "Mountain View, CA");

            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(txtFile.Text, "video/quicktime");
            Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UploadLimit
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the user's videos and get the latest date:

```
var videos = new YouTubeRequest().GetVideoFeed(userId).Entries
DateTime lastUploadDate = videos.Max(video => video.YouTubeEntry.Published)
```

To get the actual video's title:

```
var lastVideo = videos.Where(video => video.YouTubeEntry.Published == lastUploadDate).First();
var name = lastVideo.Title
```

Comment: Sorted that issue now, thanks :-)


Do you know how I can get the name of the latest video uploaded by that particular user?

Comment: @user3329169 yes. just find the video with that date, and use the `Title` property.

Comment: @user3329169 btw... It's probably the first or last video on the list if you want to rely on that.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean title property?

Comment: @user3329169 `var lastVideo = videos.Where(video => video.YouTubeEntry.Published == lastUploadDate).First(); var name = lastVideo.Title`